# Android library's sub dependencies in private Maven repo is not downloaded by project

Tags: android, maven, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

The Android library is hosted in a private Maven Artifactory repo in the company that I'm working in.
This library is using okhttp as a one of the dependencies.

In the application project I import this library as such:

> compile 'com.domain.artifact:myartifact:1.0.0@aar'

The library is imported, however when I call the API in the library, the application crashes with ClassNotFoundException due to missing okhttp classes.

Doing a gradle command to print dependencies shows that the application project does not download any of the library's dependency (including okhttp)

```
+--- com.domain.artifact:myartifact:1.0.0
\--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1
     \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1
          +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.1
          |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.1
          +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.0.1
          |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.1 (*)
          +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.0.1
          |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.1 (*)
          \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.0.1
```

**How can I ensure that the library's dependencies are also downloaded or published successfully?**

====== Additional Info =======

The library is published with "maven-publish" plugin, and dependency is added using "pom.withXml" in the gradle script, and okhttp is in the POM file of the library.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
    <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the **`@aar`** notation in your dependency.

It means that you want to download only the aar artifact excluding all nested dependencies.
You can check this part of [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html):
Check the `Artifact only notation` section:

> An artifact only notation creates a module dependency which downloads only the artifact file with the specified extension. **Existing module descriptors are ignored**.

Using the `@aar` notation if you want to download the dependencies, you should add `transitive=true`.

I'd expect that omitting @aar it should work.

Comment: It works !! It is so obvious, but I didn't see that. On the side note, I remember encountering a dependency error when i removed "@aar" notation few days ago, but I can't seems to replicate that now. It was something like "jar artifact not found" when the library only has aar file in artifactory.